# What sed script can replace a range of hex characters with another

Tags: search, replace, sed, binary, hex

I need to replace some non text characters in some automatically generated files with spaces.
Although they are text files after processing some characters are added and the cannot be edited as text any more

Is there a sed command to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your platform and `sed` version, you may or may not be able to do something like `s/[\000-\037]/ /g`; but the portable and simple alternative is this:

```
tr '\000-\037' ' ' <input >output
```

(All character codes are "binary"; I have assumed you mean control characters, but if you mean 8-bit characters `\200-\377` or something else altogether, it's obviously trivial to adjust the range.)

Comment: I think they are characters in the 128-255 range. Some faulty processing is adding them and text editors cannot open them. When I do a grep with color highlighting they are visible and appear as ?. Can some faulty UTF-8 based processing cause that?

Comment: That's `\200-\377` octal then. Can't really speculate about the reason without knowing more, but it doesn't sound particularly like a UTF-8 problem, no.

Comment: Consider `tr -c '[:print:]\n' ' '`